# How to spark-submit a script directly on terminal instead of using a script file?

Tags: apache-spark, terminal, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I have some jobs that use a the following command to execute some tasks:

```
pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --py-files file.py --name file file.py
```

The script on my python file is very simple:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext;
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext;
sc =SparkContext();
hive_context = HiveContext(sc);
table_1 = hive_context.sql("SELECT * FROM table_1");
table_1.write.insertInto("table_to_insert", overwrite=True);
```

My question is: can I run this command directly with the script instead of using a file? Something like:

```
"pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --py-script 'from pyspark import SparkContext; from pyspark.sql import HiveContext; sc =SparkContext(); hive_context = HiveContext(sc); table_1 = hive_context.sql("SELECT * FROM table_1"); table_1.write.insertInto("table_to_insert", overwrite=True);'"
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks for your support!

Comment: What is your real goal here - why are you trying to avoid using a file?

Comment: I'm using a orchestration tool to run my jobs. If I have opportunity to run all the jobs directly on terminal it will much better than have to create multiple files external to the tool